# Create Bar plot in Highcharter library [R Programming]

Tags: r, visualization, sentiment-analysis, r-highcharter

I have created a simple barplot from sentiment analysis in R, I was studying high charter and was trying to create the same barplot in the high charter. The dataset is simple as below

```
  anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive
1     0            2       0    0   2       0        1     2        0        3
2     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     1        0        1
3     0            0       0    0   0       0        0     0        0        1
4     0            2       0    0   2       0        1     2        0        2
5     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     0        0        2
6     0            3       0    0   2       0        1     2        0        2
7     0            0       0    0   0       0        0     0        0        0
```

```
barplot(colSums(s),
        las = 3,
        col = rainbow(10),
        ylab = 'Count',
        main = 'Sentiment Scores')
```

With the output below

[image]

Any suggestions how I might be able to make the same reactive graph in highcharter? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you create a simple summary data.frame including the sentiments and scores from your data.

```
df <- data.frame(sentiment = names(s), score = colSums(s))
```

Then you can reference this in `hchart` to create your barplot.

```
library(highcharter)

hchart(df, 'column', hcaes(x = sentiment, y = score, color = rainbow(10)))
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks alot.